# Getting location(city, state) from ip_address for bulk data with rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip-address, rake-task, geocode

I have an x users with their last_sign_in_ip, can i get their location details using their ip_address with rake task?
I am using rails and geocoder gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the geocoder gem, use this:

```
Geocoder.search(user.last_sign_in_ip)
```

It will return a json with the address elements.

Answer (score 0):

please use `search` method from `Geocoder` see below code

```
Geocoder.search(ip)
```

In your case

```
location = Geocoder.search(last_sign_in_ip)
```

And from `location` you will get all the address details.

Comment: How is your answer bringing more information than the one I've posted ? Plus, last_sign_in_ip probably applies to a user so this won't work